# Sorting a dataframe by index

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe called df that is indexed by date which I am trying to sort oldest date to newest.

I have tried to use both:

```
df = df.sort(axis=1)
```

and:

```
df = df.sort_index(axis=1)
```

but as you can see from the date order in the following df tail the dates have not been sorted into date order.

```
                            wood_density  
date                                      
2016-01-27                        5.8821  
2016-01-28                        5.7760  
2015-12-25                           NaN  
2016-01-01                           NaN  
2015-12-26                           NaN
```

What can I try to resolve this?

Comment: `axis=1` sorts columns; `axis=0` (the default) sorts rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) to sort the index:

```
In [19]:

df = df.sort_index()
df
Out[19]:
            wood_density
date                    
2015-12-25           NaN
2015-12-26           NaN
2016-01-01           NaN
2016-01-27        5.8821
2016-01-28        5.7760
```

`sort`, which is deprecated by `sort_values` or `sort_index` sorts on row labels by default `axis=0` so it would've worked if you didn't pass this:

```
In [21]:
df.sort()

Out[21]:
            wood_density
date                    
2015-12-25           NaN
2015-12-26           NaN
2016-01-01           NaN
2016-01-27        5.8821
2016-01-28        5.7760
```